# How to get condor_q to show detailed information of the jobs I submitted?

Tags: distributed-computing, condor

This is driving me crazy, because it should be very simple and yet I can't seem to make it work. When I look at the documentation for Condor, I see that the `condor_q` command should return information in this format [[Source]](https://htcondor.readthedocs.io/en/latest/users-manual/managing-a-job.html):

```
 ID      OWNER            SUBMITTED     RUN_TIME ST PRI SIZE CMD
711197.0   aragorn         1/15 19:18   0+04:29:33 H  0   0.0  script.sh
894381.0   frodo           3/16 09:06  82+17:08:51 R  0   439.5 elk elk.in
894386.0   frodo           3/16 09:06  82+20:21:28 R  0   219.7 elk elk.in
894388.0   frodo           3/16 09:06  81+17:22:10 R  0   439.5 elk elk.in
1086870.0   gollum          4/27 09:07   0+00:10:14 I  0   7.3  condor_dagman
```

With each job having its own line and info related to it. Yet every time I run `condor_q`, I get this summary format instead:

```
OWNER    BATCH_NAME    SUBMITTED   DONE   RUN    IDLE  TOTAL JOB_IDS
studid    CMD: java    7/13 17:27     _    292      _    460 64482.12 ... 64491.9

292 jobs; 0 completed, 0 removed, 0 idle, 292 running, 0 held, 0 suspended
```

I have tried a bunch of different options listen in the help section of the command but nothing seems to work. It's making it very difficult to manage my jobs right now, and understand what is still running and what is not. Not sure if it matters, but the Condor cluster is my University's.

I would greatly appreciate any tip you folks may have.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If anyone stumbles over this and has my same problem, the command I was looking for turned out to be `condor_q -nobatch`. Apparently the non-batch version used to be the norm, and now they changed it so that the batch output is the default.